# Mimicking _n in Stata to generate a dummy variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, stata, tidyverse

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
fact_code style_serial
1004      style_101
1004      style_101
1004      style_101
1004      style_102
1004      style_102
1004      style_102
5002      style_101
5002      style_101
5002      style_101
5002      style_102
5002      style_102
5002      style_102
```

where `fact_code` is the factory code, and `style_serial` is the serial number of the garment style that the factory produces. What I am trying to generate, is a variable, `ss`, that looks like this:

```
fact_code style_serial ss
1004      style_101    1
1004      style_101    0
1004      style_101    0
1004      style_102    1
1004      style_102    0
1004      style_102    0
5002      style_101    1
5002      style_101    0
5002      style_101    0
5002      style_102    1
5002      style_102    0
5002      style_102    0
```

Basically, this variable, `ss`, can be generated by the Stata code as follows:

```
bysort fact_code style_serial: gen ss=_n==1
```

`_n` is Stata notation for the current observation number.

But I am trying to generate the same dummy variable, `ss`, using R but keep getting errors. These are the R codes that I have tried to mimic the above Stata code:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>% 
  mutate(ss = n_distinct(fact_code, style_serial))
```

and

```
mydf <- mydf %>% group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>% 
  mutate(ss =  ave(mydf$fact_code, mydf$style_serial, FUN = seq_along))
```

The name of the R dataframe is `mydf`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mutate(s = as.integer(row_number() == 1L))`? I guess this is not so useful in R as in Stata, though.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `duplicated()`.

```
df1$ss <- with(df1, ifelse(duplicated(df1), 0, 1))
```

***Yields***

```
> df1
   fact_code style_serial ss
1       1004    style_101  1
2       1004    style_101  0
3       1004    style_101  0
4       1004    style_102  1
5       1004    style_102  0
6       1004    style_102  0
7       5002    style_101  1
8       5002    style_101  0
9       5002    style_101  0
10      5002    style_102  1
11      5002    style_102  0
12      5002    style_102  0
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="fact_code style_serial
1004      style_101
                  1004      style_101
                  1004      style_101
                  1004      style_102
                  1004      style_102
                  1004      style_102
                  5002      style_101
                  5002      style_101
                  5002      style_101
                  5002      style_102
                  5002      style_102
                  5002      style_102")
```